# Как организовать БД пользователей с правами на SQL под приложение на C#

Tags: авторизация

Есть приложение на C#, которому нужна нормальная система авторизации и хранения данных.
Есть идея сделать SQL БД для организации пользователей, групп, и управления правами.
Вопрос - как организовать подобное? Есть ли туториалы? Или, может есть более простой, удобный, или правильный способ?
sql выбран по причине параллельного изучения, и отсутствия идей лучше.

Comment: Приложение серверное или аппликация? Авторизация исходит из каких данных? Где хранятся эти данные и как они администрируются и заводиться?

Comment: Приложение на формах windows, авторизация ... по логину и паролю, данные могут быть и на сервере в локальной сети, и в виде подключаемой  локальной базы. БД заводится заранее (сервер), или создается при установке/запуске приложения (локальная БД). Пока такие мысли. Из всего, что нашел в учебниках предлагают хранить логин/пароль в табличке из 3х "полей" - id | Username | Password. Меня так-же интересует способ организации групп и прав, безопасность, или абсолютно другой, более удобный, или подходящий способ.

Comment: Локально это просто без смысла, если это регулирует доступ к приложению. Попробуйте [это](http://www.litedb.org)

Comment: А если всё-же серверное решение?

Comment: Так а в чем вопрос? Работа с удаленной sql базой? Возьмите FE6, там все в двух строках поместится.

Comment: Вопрос - где найти годные учебные пособия или варианты решения, чтоб велосипед из костылей не городить.

Comment: Обычно в гугле :) [EF6 example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/entity-framework-introduction-using-c-sharp-part-one/), [EF Code-First Example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx)

Comment: Не только про EF6, я просто не знаю как организовать ХОРОШО.